# Android : Unable to update state in widget because updateWidget not called

Tags: android

Am trying to update the widget text with the WiFi Supplicant state (i.e. if the WiFi is connecting, authenticating, etc). I used a broadcast receiver to get notified of the supplicant state changes so I can call the update on the widget accordingly. The receiver is called correctly & am receiving all the supplicant state changes. But am calling updateAppWidget() method to update the text field in the widget inside that receiver and that is not happening. I think the supplicant state change is too fast (i.e. when WiFi is getting on, it changes quickly from 'scanning' to 'connecting' to 'authenticating' and so on) that the widget update is not even being called. But I see that there are widgets who are showing it even if it's fast. Is there any problem with my code:

```
    public class Widget_AppWidgetProvider_WiFiInfo_Basic
        extends AppWidgetProvider {


    static Widget_Specific_WiFi_Info widgetSpecificWiFiInfo = null;
    Context currentContext = null;
    boolean scanStop = false;
    // Custom Intent name for handling when the user taps on the widget
    private static final String WIDGET_TAP_ACTION_NAME = "wifi.widgets.WIDGET_WIFI_TAPPED";
    // Custom Intent name that is used by the AlarmManager to tell us to update the clock once per 10seconds
    public static String WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION_NAME = "wifi.widgets.UPDATE_widget_wifi";
    // Stores the last tap time, in order to say if the last tap was a consecutive 2nd or 3rd tap, say, or the first one
    private static long lastWidgetTapTime = Constants.INVALID_LONG;
    private static long currentWidgetTapTime = Constants.INVALID_LONG;
    private static int widgetTapCount = Constants.INVALID_NUMBER;
    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverWiFiStateChange = null;
//    BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiverWiFiSupplicantStateChange = null;
    // A variable used to track the change in WiFi connection states
    private static int lastWifiConnState = Constants.INVALID_NUMBER;
    private static String lastWiFiSupplicantState = Constants.EMPTY_STRING;



    private void initializeWidget() {

        if (this.currentContext == null) {
            return;
        }

        RemoteViews widgetView = new RemoteViews(currentContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_wifi);
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        this.currentContext = context;

        if (WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION_NAME.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            // Get the widget manager and ids for this widget provider, then call the shared
            // clock update method.
            ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
            for (int appWidgetID : ids) {
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);
            }
        }

        else if (WIDGET_TAP_ACTION_NAME.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "got tap event");


            // Is it the first time the user is tapping (meaning, consecutively) the widget?
            if (widgetTapCount == Constants.INVALID_NUMBER) {
                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "first tap");
                widgetTapCount = 1;
                lastWidgetTapTime = currentWidgetTapTime = (new Date()).getTime();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "tap first but nothing else. so resetting");
                        if (widgetTapCount == 1) {
                            Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "tap count still 1. no next tap yet. resetting.");
                            widgetTapCount = Constants.INVALID_NUMBER;
                            lastWidgetTapTime = currentWidgetTapTime = Constants.INVALID_LONG;
                        }
                    }
                }, 1000);


            } else {

                widgetTapCount++;
                lastWidgetTapTime = currentWidgetTapTime;
                currentWidgetTapTime = (new Date()).getTime();
                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "Last tap time=" + lastWidgetTapTime);
                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "Current tap time=" + currentWidgetTapTime);
                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "Tap count=" + widgetTapCount);
            }


            if (widgetTapCount >= 2) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        // Double tap - Toggle WiFi on/off in the device
                        if (widgetTapCount == 2) {
                                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "Double tap - toggle WiFi state");
                                MyWiFiManager wiFiManager = new MyWiFiManager(currentContext);
                                wiFiManager.toggleDeviceWiFiState();

                                // Get the widget manager and ids for this widget provider, then call the shared
                                // clock update method.
                                ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
                                AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                                int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
                                for (int appWidgetID : ids) {
                                    updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);
                                }

                                widgetTapCount = Constants.INVALID_NUMBER;
                                lastWidgetTapTime = currentWidgetTapTime = Constants.INVALID_LONG;

                        }
                        // Triple Tap : Open WiFi Settings page
                        else if (widgetTapCount == 3) {
                            Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "triple tap");
                            currentContext.getApplicationContext().startActivity((new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
                            widgetTapCount = Constants.INVALID_NUMBER;
                            lastWidgetTapTime = currentWidgetTapTime = Constants.INVALID_LONG;
                        }


                    }
                }, 500);

            }
        }
    }



    private void initializeWifiStateChangeReceiver() {

//        Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "initializeWifiScanReceiver");

        broadcastReceiverWiFiStateChange = new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

//                MyWiFiManager wiFiManager = new MyWiFiManager(currentContext);
//                String currentSupplicantState = wiFiManager.getSupplicantStateAsString();
//                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "WiFi connection state change ; now=" + currentSupplicantState);
                ConnectivityManager conMan = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                int currentWiFiConnState = Constants.INVALID_NUMBER;
                boolean wifiStateChanged = false;
                boolean supplicantStateChanged = false;

                if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {

                    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "Have Wifi Connection");
                    currentWiFiConnState = Constants.WIFI_CONN_IS_THERE;
                    if (lastWifiConnState == Constants.WIFI_CONN_IS_NOT_THERE) {
                        currentWiFiConnState = Constants.WIFI_CONN_IS_THERE;
                        wifiStateChanged = true;
                    }
                }

                else {
                    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "Don't have Wifi Connection");
                    currentWiFiConnState = Constants.WIFI_CONN_IS_NOT_THERE;
                    if (lastWifiConnState == Constants.WIFI_CONN_IS_THERE) {
                        currentWiFiConnState = Constants.WIFI_CONN_IS_NOT_THERE;
                        wifiStateChanged = true;
                    }


                    if (!(currentSupplicantState.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.WIFI_SUPPLICANT_STATE_OBTAINING_IPADDR))) {
                        if (lastWiFiSupplicantState.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.EMPTY_STRING)) {
                             lastWiFiSupplicantState = currentSupplicantState;
                            supplicantStateChanged = true;
                        } else {
                            if (!(lastWiFiSupplicantState.equalsIgnoreCase(currentSupplicantState))) {
                                supplicantStateChanged = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME,
                            "lastWiFiSupplicantState=" + lastWiFiSupplicantState +
                            "\ncurrentSupplicantState=" + currentSupplicantState
                    + "supplicantStateChanged=" + supplicantStateChanged);

                }

                // Update the widget info in case the wifi conn state has changed
                if ((wifiStateChanged) || (supplicantStateChanged)) {
                    Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "WiFi connection changed. Updating widgets.");
                    lastWifiConnState = currentWiFiConnState;
                    lastWiFiSupplicantState = currentSupplicantState;

                    ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
                    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                    int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
                    for (int appWidgetID : ids) {
                        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }


    private PendingIntent createWidgetIntent(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION_NAME);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        return pendingIntent;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDisabled(Context context) {
        super.onDisabled(context);
//      Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "wcg : onDisabled");
        //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Widget Provider disabled. Turning off timer");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(createWidgetIntent(context));

        currentContext.unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiverWiFiStateChange);
    }


    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context) {

        super.onEnabled(context);
        Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "wcg info : onEnabled");
        this.currentContext = context;
        this.initializeWidget();
        Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "wcg info : Widget Provider enabled.  Starting timer to update widget every 10seconds");
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 10, createWidgetIntent(context));
    }



    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        widgetSpecificWiFiInfo = new Widget_Specific_WiFi_Info();
        widgetSpecificWiFiInfo.contextCurrent = this.currentContext;


        initializeWifiStateChangeReceiver();
//        initializeWifiSupplicantStateChangeReceiver();
        context.getApplicationContext()
                .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverWiFiStateChange, new IntentFilter(
                        WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));
        context.getApplicationContext()
                .registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverWiFiStateChange, new IntentFilter(
                        WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION));


        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
            // to the button
            RemoteViews widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_wifi);
            widgetView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layout_wifi, getPendingSelfIntent(context, WIDGET_TAP_ACTION_NAME));

            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, widgetView);
            // Update the widget components using a shared method
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }



    public static void updateAppWidget(final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int appWidgetId) {

        Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "wcg info basic : updateAppWidget");
        final RemoteViews widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_wifi);

        setFonts(widgetView,
                Utility.getDeviceDensity(context),
                Utility.getDeviceHeight(context));

        // Set the supplicant state
        String supplicantState = (new MyWiFiManager(context)).getSupplicantStateAsString();
        if ( ! (supplicantState.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.WIFI_SUPPLICANT_STATE_OBTAINING_IPADDR))) {
            widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text_ssid, supplicantState);
        }

        if (widgetSpecificWiFiInfo != null) {

            final HashMap<String, String> mapWiFiInfo = widgetSpecificWiFiInfo.getCurrentWiFiValues(context);

            if (mapWiFiInfo != null) {

                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "mapWiFiInfo not null ; supplicant=" + (new MyWiFiManager(context)).getSupplicantStateAsString());

                if (!(MyWiFiManager.isInternetConnected(context))) {

                    setUIValuesWhenNoWiFiConnection(widgetView);

                } else {

                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, widgetView);

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            boolean nothingYet = false;

                            // Make them visible in case they had been made invisible earlier (eg., when no WiFi connection)
                            widgetView.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm, View.VISIBLE);
                            widgetView.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm_unit, View.VISIBLE);

                            // Set the WiFi values in the Widget's components
                            String tempVar = mapWiFiInfo.get(Constants.WIFI_STAT_RSSI);
                            if ((tempVar != null) && (tempVar.length() > 0)) {
                                int signalStrengthAsInt = Integer.parseInt(tempVar);
                                if (signalStrengthAsInt < -100) {
                                    tempVar = Constants.WIFI_SIGNAL_DBM_LOWER_THRESHOLD;
                                }
                                widgetView.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm_unit, View.VISIBLE);
                                widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm,
                                        ((tempVar.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.WIFI_SIGNAL_DBM_LOWER_THRESHOLD)) ? Constants.NOTHING_YET : tempVar));
                                // if the signal strength received is invalid, hide the unit i.e. dBm textfield
                                if (tempVar.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.WIFI_SIGNAL_DBM_LOWER_THRESHOLD)) {
                                    widgetView.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm_unit, View.INVISIBLE);
                                }

                            } else {
                                nothingYet = true;
                            }


                            tempVar = mapWiFiInfo.get(Constants.WIFI_STAT_SSID);
                            widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text_ssid,
                                    (((tempVar == null) || (tempVar.length() == 0)) ?
                                            Constants.MSG_WIFI_NOT_CONNECTED : tempVar));



                            // Looks like we didn't get any valid WiFi values
                            // So set the UI values accordingly
                            if (nothingYet) {
                                setUIValuesWhenWiFiStillConnecting(widgetView, Utility.getDeviceDensity(context));
                            }

                            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, widgetView);

                        }
                    }, 1 * 1000);  // show the progress bar for a second just to indicate data refresh
                } // end of else

            } else {
                Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "mapwifiinfo is null");
            }

        } else {
            Log.d(Constants.APP_NAME, "wcg info : object null");
            widgetSpecificWiFiInfo = new Widget_Specific_WiFi_Info();
            widgetSpecificWiFiInfo.contextCurrent = context;
        }

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, widgetView);
    }



    protected PendingIntent getPendingSelfIntent(Context context, String action) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, getClass());
        intent.setAction(action);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    }




    private static void setUIValuesWhenNoWiFiConnection(RemoteViews widgetView) {

        widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text_ssid, Constants.MSG_WIFI_NOT_CONNECTED);
        widgetView.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm, View.INVISIBLE);
        widgetView.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm_unit, View.INVISIBLE);
    }



    private static void setUIValuesWhenWiFiStillConnecting (RemoteViews widgetView, float deviceDensity) {

        widgetView.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm, View.VISIBLE);
        widgetView.setViewVisibility(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm_unit, View.INVISIBLE);

        widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text_ssid, Constants.MSG_WIFI_NOT_CONNECTED);
        widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm,
                Constants.NOTHING_YET);
    }




    private static void setFonts(RemoteViews widgetView,
                                 float deviceDensity,
                                 float deviceHeight) {

        // ~~~~~~~~~ FOR SIGNAL STRENGTH ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        float fontSizeSignalStrength = 26f;
        float fontSizeSignalStrengthUnit = 20f;
        float fontSizeSSID = 22f;

        widgetView.setFloat(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm,
                Constants.METHOD_SETTEXTSIZE,
                fontSizeSignalStrength);
        widgetView.setFloat(R.id.widget_text_signal_strength_dbm_unit,
                Constants.METHOD_SETTEXTSIZE,
                fontSizeSignalStrengthUnit);
        widgetView.setFloat(R.id.widget_text_ssid,
                Constants.METHOD_SETTEXTSIZE,
                fontSizeSSID);
    }

}
```

**1st EDIT**

I tried this based on @Rithe's comment. In the broadcast receiver which listens for network state changes:

```
                if (wifiStateChanged) {
AppWidgetManager widgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                    ComponentName widgetComponent = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
                    int[] widgetIds = widgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(widgetComponent);
                    Intent update = new Intent();
                    update.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, widgetIds);
                    update.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
                    context.sendBroadcast(update);
                }
```

and this in the onReceive() of the Widget

```
if (WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION_NAME.equals(intent.getAction())) {

            /*
            ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), getClass().getName());
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);
            for (int appWidgetID : ids) {
                updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetID);
            }
            */
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
            int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, this.getClass()));

            onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        }
```

But nothing happening yet. onUpdate is not called.

Answer (score 0):

i think changes on textviews etc. during runtime can only be done in onUpdate.

i also faced the problem that onUpdate never got called. i found a **realy dirty solution** for that: call onUpdate for specific broadcasts in your onReceive method like this:

**Android Manifest** - set specific Action

```
<receiver
  android:name="your widget"
  ...>
  <intent-filter>
    ...
    <action android:name="your.package.path.ACTION_NAME/>
  </intent-filter>
  <meta-data
    .../>
</receiver>
```

**Widget onReceive**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  super.onReceive(context, intent);

  ...

  if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("your.package.path.ACTION_NAME")) {
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, this.getClass()));
    appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetIds, ...);

    onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
  }    
}
```

**Broadcast Receiver onReceive**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
  ...
  Intent update = new Intent("your.package.path.ACTION_NAME");
  update.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, widgetIds);
  context.sendBroadcast(update);
}
```

so you can handle all your ui changes of your widget in your onUpdate method.

Comment: thanks @Rithe for your response. I tried this, but still onUpdate is not called! :(

Comment: hmm... can pls post the whole class. it is hard to say just by the onReceive method

Comment: pasted the entire class above. Please check

Comment: in your broadcast receiver you should fire an action intent which the widget is listening to. then the onReceive of the widget gets called and there (and not in the onReceive of the broadcast receiver) you can call the onUpdate of the widget.

Comment: please see the code under '1st edit' I posted in the question. onUpdate() is not called even then.

Comment: you are checking for if(WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION_NAME.equals(intent.getAction())), but you don't set WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION_NAME action in your intent of the broadcast receiver. is it possible, that the onUpdate() method does not get called in your onReceive?

Comment: I tried with                     update.setAction(WIDGET_UPDATE_ACTION_NAME);
also. onUpdate() is not called @Rithe

Comment: i updated my answer a bit (also the onReceive of the widget) for better understanding. if this does not work, i'm also out of ideas ;)